# php POST and non-english language chars passes empty

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to program a Hebrew site with a search option.
(old site and the charset of this site is windows-1255)
I am using php 5.2 with Apache 2.2, on a Debian 5 (Lenny) with
appropriate code pages enabled.

I am using _POST to pass arguments to a script. If I pass
English word to the script everything works, but when I use Hebrew
nothing is passed through the POST function. When I use ECHO
to show _POST, the variable is empty.

What might be the problem?

P.S. this is old site that worked fine on PHP 4 with debian 4, and the problem arised only
after we upgrade to PHP5+debian5.

Comment: no , the site run with windows-1255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks guys , its my fault

the problem solve !

we have a class filter that recognize that is in php5 
and run

```
filter_var($this->source[$var], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, (FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH));
```

and this sanitize the hebrew chars post to empty .!

Answer (score 1):

Try the tips under "Programming Considerations" of [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-unicode/index.html):

> ```
> *  Explicit use of UTF-8, marked with
>       o "mb_language('uni'); mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');" at the top of your scripts
>       o Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 in the HTTP header, by way of .htaccess, header() or Web server configuration
>       o <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> and <orm accept-charset = "utf-8"> in HTML markup
>       o CREATE DATABASE ... DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8 ... ENGINE ... CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci is a typical sequence for a MySQL instance, with comparable expressions for other databases
>       o SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' is a valuable directive for PHP to send MySQL immediately after connecting
>       o In php.ini, assign default_charset = UTF-8
> * Replacement of string functions, such as strlen and strtlower, with mb_strlen and mb_convert_case
> * Replacement of mail and colleagues with mb_send_mail, etc.; while Unicode-aware e-mail is an advanced topic beyond the scope of this introduction, the use of mb_send_mail is a good starting point
> * Use of multibyte regular expressions functions (see Resources)
> ```

Especially, in this case, the first two sub-bullet points.